# Why is the HTML comment open block valid JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, theory

In some old code, I found a JavaScript file with it's contents surrounded by HTML comments.

I understand the reasons for doing that in old browsers, but not how it is valid JavaScript in any way.

The expression `<!--` is `undefined` in Chrome and IE's console.

Is this a special case handled by the interpreter (http://javascript.about.com/library/blhtmcmt.htm) still defined in the ECMAScript standards and working in modern browsers, or does the combination of these symbols happen to result in something that's `undefined`?

I read this as something like "less-than NOT decrement", which seems nonsensical with no operands.  Any of these by themselves return a syntax error.

I get why things like "use strict"; are valid, but do nothing, but I can't tell what **this** code actually does.

I'm probably overthinking it, but would like to understand what's going on

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a non-standard feature that browsers and JavaScript engines have always implemented.  Nowadays, it cannot be removed from the Web platform, as that would break backwards compatibility. It’s [detailed in ***the JavaScript / Web ECMAScript spec***](http://javascript.spec.whatwg.org/#comment-syntax):

> `<!--` must be treated as the start of a `SingleLineComment` —
>   equivalent to `//`.
>
> ```
> var x = true;
> <!-- x = false; // note: no syntax error
> x; // true
> ```
>
> `-->` at the start of a line, optionally preceded by whitespace or
>   `MultiLineComment`s, must be treated as a `SingleLineComment` —
>   equivalent to `//`.
>
> ```
> var x = true;
> --> x = false; // note: no syntax error
> x; // true
>
> var x = 1;
> /*
> multiline comment!
> x = 2;
> */ --> x = 3;
> x; // 1
> ```

Answer (score 4):

`<!--` begins a single-line Javascript comment, believe it or not.

This is used to allow `<script>` blocks to hide themselves from browsers that don't recognize the `<script>` tag (eg, Netscape 2), by wrapping all of the script contents in an HTML comment.

This should no longer be used.

Comment: Aha!  Thanks.  That makes sense now.  This is some terribly ancient JavaScript that I'm reviewing - they must have left these in while refactoring or something and forgotten about them.

Comment: And closing tags are usually written as `//-->` making then syntactically correct as well.